# Change ulimit on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

From my rails application, I run an external process that can be very resource consuming depending of the input I pass.
Therefore I would like to be sure it wont take too much, and I want to change the ulimit.
ulimit works fine in my shell, but I soon I try to change it in rails, I get an invalid argument.

```
    $ rails c
    [1] pry(main)> `/usr/bin/ulimit -Ht`
    => "unlimited\n"
    [2] pry(main)> `/usr/bin/ulimit -Ht 1`
    /usr/bin/ulimit: line 4: ulimit: cpu time: cannot modify limit:           
    Invalid argument
```

And it's not a syntax problem, since:

```
[1] pry(main)> `/usr/bin/ulimit -Ht 'unlimited'`
=> ""
[2] pry(main)> `/usr/bin/ulimit -Ht 'wrongparam'`
/usr/bin/ulimit: line 4: ulimit: wrongparam: invalid number
=> ""
```

Not a permission problem also:

```
[5] pry(main)> `sudo ulimit -Ht 1`
Password:
/usr/bin/ulimit: line 4: ulimit: cpu time: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```

Changing the soft limit works well:

```
[10] pry(main)> `ulimit -St 1; ulimit -St`
=> "1\n"
```

Changing the hard limit in the shell that launch rails also work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

ulimit doesn't limit execution time, only cpu time so it might not have the exact effect you are looking for. you might look at `timeout`

if you are hell bent on using ulimit the best method would be to create a shell script that you call instead of trying to call ulimit directly in ruby. ulimit is typically a function of the shell so it is better to run it as such.

something like this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -Ht 1 && whateveryouaretryingtorun $1
```

and then call it

```
%x{./path/to/script arguments}
```

I havn't tested this myself as ulimit is built in to zsh so calling it in that context is a little different.

Comment: I also want to limit memory, so yeah, must use ulimit. And the bash is not the solution: the limit seems to be fixed for the whole process hierarchy, and it fails too if in a bash script.

Comment: is this another ruby script?

Comment: from what I can find this isn't limited to ruby. it seems ulimit doesn't run very well from shell outs. I can do it in pry with zsh by calling `%x{/usr/bin/zsh -c "ulimit -Ht 1"}` but as I said ulimit is bult in to zsh so I don't know if that will work for you.